# Accessing values send in first REST API request from a following request

Tags: java, rest, httpsession

I'm implementing REST APIs in Java for user registration using OTP which is going to be used in a mobile application. So for registering a user, I need to get Name, MobileNumber and EmailId through the first request and send OTP to the mobile number provided and in the second request I expect only OTP from the user and I need to validate the OTP and if validate true, I need to send all the details to database.

```
@Local
public interface RegisterUserResource {

public static final String ID = "id";

@POST
@Path( "/details" )
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
RegisterUser registerUserDetails(RegisterUser registerUser);

@POST
@Path( "/validate" )
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
RegisterUser validateUser(RegisterUser registerUser);
```

RegisterUser entity class

```
public class RegisterUser {

public static final String PATH = "/register";

public String userId;
public String name;
public String mobileNumber;
public String emailId;
public String OTP;
```

Help me to find any ways to get the details provided in first request(Name,MobileNumber,EmailId) to be used in second request in order to send them to database?

Comment: So, what help do you need? You neither mentioned any code to work with nor provided your preferred library

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I've update my question.

Comment: Why not persist the first time and on the second time just update the record?

Comment: @TaraGnana well you should create a column formally verified in your database. Add all the info from req 1 along with false to verified and your otp and then in the second request just verify the otp stored in the database, and update field as verifed to true.